# Mercurial: How to find last time my branch was merged into default

Tags: mercurial

Is there some Mercurial revision set magic that can be used to find the last changeset on the `default` branch that merged a specific branch (let's call it `mybranch`)?

Or equally good find the last revision of `mybranch` that was merged into default`?

In addition a way to list changesets grafted from `mybranch` to `default` would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hg help revsets` as source, starting from the last question

### List of grafted changesets

```
"destination([set])" 
Changesets that were created by a graft, transplant or rebase operation, with the given
revisions specified as the source.
Omitting the optional set is the same as passing all().
```

For "... changesets grafted from mybranch to default" revset will be

```
destination(branch("mybranch")) & branch("default")
```

Even better: you can store it as revsetalias (TBT!)

```
[revsetalias]
grafted(from, to) = destination(branch(from)) & branch(to)
```

and use it for *any pair* of branches (expandning to custom amount of sources will be *your* future task).

### Last merged revision

Step-by-step

- "...last changeset on the default branch that merged a specific branch" is a) mergeset b) latest if merged more once c) one of it's parents belongs to branch-in-question
- you have to test revset and if I mixed up parents, exchange p1 & p2 in revset (can't debug now)
- Revset have to be prepared for the most common task "Get the latest mergepoint of branch FROM to branch TO"

`merge() & branch("to")` - all mergepoints in TO

`p2(merge() & branch("to")) & branch("from")` - parents of the above merges only FROM

`child(p2(merge() & branch("to")) & branch("from")) & branch("to")` - childs of the above parents only in TO (because they can have childs in other branches too)

`last(child(p2(merge() & branch("to")) & branch("from")) & branch("to"))` - latest mergepoint if merges happened more than once.

Set of revsetaliases (for better readability) as result

```
[revsetalias]
ms(to) = merge() & branch(to)
```

<strike>ms2b(to,from) = (child(p2(ms(to))) & branch(from)) & branch(to)</strike>

```
fp_ms(to,from) = p2(ms(to)) & branch(from)
```

and your revset for:

- latest mergepoint `last(ms2b("default","mybranch"))`
- latest foreign parent `last(fp_ms("default","mybranch"))`

**Addition & Demonstration**

I fixed my ms2b(), as shown in THG's repobrowser screenshot below. Merges from stable to default "as is"

`children(p2(merge() & branch(default)) & branch(stable)) & branch(default)`

With parameters and previously prepared revsetaliases

`ms2b(to,from) = children(p2(ms(to)) & branch(from)) & branch(to)`

[image: RepoBrowser w/filter]

Comment: grafted() and fp_ms() works and is what I need. ms2b() does not return anything, but not important for me.

Comment: Good news. Just some notes: a) `grafted()` aliias does **not** distinguish the nature of inserted changesets and if you'll have a mix of "grafted, transplanted or rebased" changesets it will show all. b) I wrote revsets from mind without debug, and expected ms2b() functional also... will try to debug later